# Могут ли сторонние приложения на телефоне знать, есть ли у меня root права?

Tags: android, ос, root

Могут ли  third -party приложение узнать у нас есть Root  права или нет ? То есть обычное устройство как то отличается от устройства с правами роот на глазх посторонних приложении? И вообше может ли  одно third party приложение знать какие другие приложение установлены сейчас либо были установлены ?

Answer (score 1):

Могут, почему нет.
Такую проверку можно даже самому реализовать при разработке приложения в Android Studio.
Вот, например, несколько ссылок на англоязычный StackOverflow, где рассказывается, как это сделать:

[Как программно определить наличие root-прав на устройстве](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523606/how-to-find-the-rooted-device-programmatically/58304556#58304556)

[Как определить, что приложение запущено на устройстве с root-правами](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15371209/11932217)

Comment: А вообше может ли одно third party приложение знать какие другие приложение установлены сейчас либо были установлены ?

Comment: Насчёт "были установлены" не уверена, но можно проверить наличие приложений "сейчас" через Package Manager (примеры [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701623/android-how-to-check-if-my-other-apps-are-installed-on-a-device/40701648) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android))